# How to fix Windows slow response to Bluetooth mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

My mouse and keyboard often lag for a few seconds after being idle, also for just a few seconds. It's like they go to sleep and take a few seconds to wake up.

After a few experiments I concluded that this was likely specific to the Bluetooth keyboard and mouse, as I could not reproduce the issue on my built-in keyboard and trackpad.

How do I fix it? Tried running the Bluetooth trouble-shooter, didn't help. Tried updating drivers, but Windows told me they're already the latest. Currently on Windows 11, but I recall experiencing this on Windows 10, before the upgrade, although perhaps it was less noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [searching online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows%20slow%20response%20to%20bluetooth%20mouse%20and%20keyboard), I found an excellent [helpdesk geek article](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-11/how-to-fix-bluetooth-mouse-lag-in-windows-11/) on this question. It has several troubleshooting steps to try, but the one that seems to have worked immediately was *disabling power management for Bluetooth adapter*. This is done in device manager:

*Bluetooth > Intel Wireless Bluetooth > Properties > Power Management*

Untick "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

This fixed it and makes perfect sense, considering the symptoms. There are lots of pages online and on this site somewhat related to this topic, but I did not see one that was an exact match, so I thought I would share the solution, hoping it will save someone some time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Nagev!
This seems to have resolved my problem. For my issue, I would have problems with my bluetooth mouse and keyboard having a small delay at the start of use. As long as a device was used it was fine but if I let it go idle for more that ~5-10s then it would have the delay again and it seemed to only happen after the computer had woken from sleep. This happened even on wall power and I had tried reinstalling bluetooth drivers and everything else. Thanks again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).